# Is it possible to send an email on remote (offline) machine through ssh?

Tags: linux, email, curl, ssh

I am monitoring some machines that aren't connected to the internet and can only be reached through a VPN. I currently connect to the VPN, and then use puTTY to ssh into the machines. I have a script automatically running a health check daily, which I then have to pull off manually with winSCP. I was wondering if it is possible to automate sending these logs with curl. I have tried using this command and ones like it:

```
curl --ssl-reqd \
  --url 'smtps://smtp.gmail.com:465' \
  --user 'username@gmail.com:password123' \
  --mail-from 'username@gmail.com' \
  --mail-rcpt 'superuser@outlook.com' \
  --upload-file mail.txt
```

Where mail.txt is a file similar to this.

```
From: "User Name" <username@gmail.com>
To: "Super User" <superuser@outlook.com>
Subject: Curl test

Message Body
```

But i get errors similar to this:

```
gnutls_handshake() failed: Error in the pull function
```

I think this stems from the fact that on these machines you can't even ping sites like google.com.

So my question is, is there a way, preferably with curl, to send emails with attachments through the ssh connection itself? The machines are Ubuntu 16.04 if that matters.

Thanks

Comment: You need to configure a proxy that goes through an SSH tunnel.

Comment: Try with ssh -D 8080 user@server.at.home -p 443

Comment: If you can `ssh` into the system, you could `scp` the files then.